# How to improve slow uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am in the process of converting a website to upload user submitted photos and videos directly to Amazon S3 instead of to the local server.

When I worked with small image files, it seemed fine... but now that I try with larger images say over 1MB, the upload speed is too slow and unusable.

What are the common strategies to overcome this? Do websites like YouTube first upload to their local server and then move to Google Cloud or something? If I have thousands of users uploading at the same time, my local server won't be able to store so many files hence I was moving to S3 before realising how slow it was.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: "Do websites like YouTube first upload to their local server and then move to Google Cloud or something?" what anyone operating at YouTube's scale is doing is almost certainly irrelevant to your situation; they're able to build their entire network infrastructure to perfectly suit their use case. GCP is basically them renting out excess hardware, and YT's backend is almost certainly exercising functionality and services not available to GCP customers.

Comment: How are you uploading?  What tools or APIs are you using?  How fast are things uploading?  How fast do you expect them to upload?  For the most part, S3 upload is one of those things where I never expect to be the bottleneck on my side (ignoring small files, or cases where S3 isn't a good fit).  Without more details, we can only guess why you think the upload is slow.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would take the following steps:

- Enable [Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) on your S3 bucket.
- Change your application to upload files in multiple parts, using S3 [Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html), and use multi-threading to upload more than one part at a time.

Comment: why is multipart needed? Will acceleration still work if not multipart from client?

Comment: @zumzum Multipart and Transfer Acceleration are not related. Multipart Upload is generally faster because it can make full use of your available upload bandwidth.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, Because `Too many log is printed in console`,The Amazon S3 upload was very slow. A 36MB file took for uploading 3 minute.

```
2022-07-12T12:58:48 DEBUG - http-outgoing-2 >> "[0x98][\r][0xd3][0xe][0xf9][0xe][0x3][0xe][0xdf][0x9][0xde][0x5]0[0x4]F[0x1][0xaa][0xfd][0xb0][0xfa][0x8d][0xf8][0xfa][0xf9][0xde][0xfa][0xb7][0xf9]E[0xfa][0xf][0xfa]*[0xfb][0xce][0xfb][0xc4][0xfa][0xed][0xf9]X[0xfa][0xee][0xfb][0xfa][0xfc][0x8a][0xfd][0x10][0xff][0x94][0xff]:[0x1]L[0x5]$[0x8]Z[\n]" [org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:73]
2022-07-12T12:58:48 DEBUG - http-outgoing-2 >> "#[0xc]&[0xb][0xac][0x9]g[0x9]+[0x9][0xae][0x7][0xf2][0x5][0x11][0x6]8[0x5]<[0x3][0x13][0x0][0x9d][0xfe]7[0xff]%[0xfe][0xc2][0xfb]J[0xfa][0xac][0xf9][0x8b][0xf7]8[0xf4][0xc1][0xf1][0xdd][0xf0][[0xf1][0xb7][0xf3]/[0xf5]/[0xf7][0x8a][0xfb]J[0x2][0xe4][0x7][0xd1][\n]" [org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:73]
2022-07-12T12:58:48 DEBUG - http-outgoing-2 >> "[0xc2][0xc][0x99][\r],[\r][[0xe]T[\r][0x80][0x9][0x10][0x7][0xad][0x2]][0xfd][0x8f][0xf8]([0xf6]^[0xf4][0x96][0xf2]?[0xf0]D[0xef][0xb2][0xf0][0xac][0xf2][0xb3][0xf3][0xbc][0xf4],[0xf8]l[0xfb]l[0xff][0xfa][0x3][0x82][0x7][0xd8][\n]" [org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:73]
2022-07-12T12:58:48 DEBUG - http-outgoing-2 >> "[0xb3][\r][0xb7][\r][[\r]=[\r][0xf7][0xb][0xb3][\n]" [org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:73]
2022-07-12T12:58:48 DEBUG - http-outgoing-2 >> "([0xb][0x9c][\n]" [org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:73]
2022-07-12T12:58:48 DEBUG - http-outgoing-2 >> "5[\n]" [org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:73]
....
```

Therefore, I turn off the log in `logback.xml`

```
<logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="WARN"/>
```

and then The 36MB file took for uploading from 3 minute to 9 seconds.

Comment: what is the logback.xml and how to edit it as you did?

Comment: @Selorb the logback is library of java log . I recommand you find your log library. and then turn off spscific logs which are too many printed,if the libray supports to turn off spscific logs.

Comment: Just faced the same problem with react/nodejs and s3 multipart upload. I just commented all the log (both in my front and back) and my 26mb file took 13sec instead of 3min30. Thank you